# How do run a task in background and even if app terminated in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I need to run a task at a specified time even if my app in the background or terminated in Xamarin Forms(Android and iOS). Please suggest me the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is in the background you can run background services and let do whatever whenever,
If your application is totally terminated you cannot do anything.

The only way to do it if your application is terminated by push notification when your application receive the notification you can run your code but the user have to click on the notifications.

Comment: Thanks. Any reference article for background services?

Comment: Check this:

https://www.google.ae/amp/s/xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-background-tasks/amp/

And this
https://github.com/winstongubantes/MatchaBackgroundService

Answer (score 1):

TYou can't write, Because each platform has their own way and rules for background services. You have to make services for each platform.

I don't want to be that guy that says "Google it" - but there are a number of tutorials directly from Xamarin that explain backgrounding. Have you looked? Getting your information directly from Xamarin is always the first place to start.

docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/

video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1YzyreS4-o